# Yii2 RBAC group assignment confusion

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I am trying to implement RBAC in my project by following the tutorial* on the Yii website. However I am confused when trying to implement the permissions by group.

For this example I have added a `group` field into the user table and have defined two groups, `user (2)` and `admin (1)`.

I then created a console command which looks like this:

```
class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = \Yii::$app->authManager;

        $rule = new \app\rbac\UserGroupRule;
        $auth->add($rule);

        $search = $auth->createPermission('search');
        $search->description = 'Search';
        $search->ruleName = $rule->name;
        $auth->add($search);

        $user = $auth->createRole('user');
        $user->ruleName = $rule->name;
        $auth->add($user);

        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->ruleName = $rule->name;
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $user);
    }
}
```

And I have this file: rbac/UserGroupRule.php

```
class UserGroupRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'userGroup';

    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        // return true; // force return to true for test
        if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $group = Yii::$app->user->identity->group;
            if($item->name === 'search') {
                return $group == 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test the permission with `if(\Yii::$app->user->can('search'))`.

1. Firstly, I wonder why the console command is required here as I can't see where it's being used.
2. The $item parameter in the execute method has the value of `search`, but the tutorial shows that it expects this value to be role type.
3. Regardless of what I return in the execute method, it seems to return false.

Can anyone answer these questions?

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an authManager with DbManager ?

```
'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
```

1. to init the rbac from the console just use `yii rbac/init` in a console (in correct project dir) then the database entries were done (before that the rbac tables should be empty)

   if you haven't done yet create the tables with

   ```
   yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
   ```
2. $item is just the auth permission or role entry. The rule is called for every entry, if you have added a rule. In your case for permission "search" and roles "user" and "admin" the rules is executed.
3. your have added entries with rule checking. So if you e.g. check if the user can "search" by e.g.

   ```
   if (\Yii::$app->user->can('search')) {
    // can search
   }
   ```

   then the rule is checked or executed (which is your UserGroupRule). And in your case it would return `true` for `admins` and `false` for `user` given by the `group` field.

edit:
I hope you have added this to your components in your config file.

```
return [
// ...
'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
    // ...
],
];
```

You have created 2 roles in your rbac (user/admin) and as far as i understand your are using a group column in the User table to allocate those roles to the user. And in your code you will need to have to check the permissions or roles. So from the DB the correct Entry is selected and if a Rule is attached this rule is then executed. And this checks the current user group and returns true or false. So in your case no assignments to those roles or permissions are done. It uses the Rule to return true or false depending on the user group. But here are other extensions search for yii2admin or yii2rbac, where you can also assign user to roles/permissions etc by database entries.

I would say you should get more help where you can "chat" e.g. the yii chat which is linked on the yii homepage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I should have mentioned I am using DbManager and yes I have ran the console script to populate the tables. However you'll see the commented line in execute returns true but this doesn't seem to register with `if(\Yii::$app->user->can('search'));`. You've given me encouragement that I'm on the right track and I'll look at it again when I get to work in the morning.

Comment: I would try to debug if your `$group = Yii::$app->user->identity->group;` is correctly returned. the group must be `1` for the admin user and `2` for a normal user. try to print that out in your `UserGroupRule` e.g. by `die(Yii::$app->user->identity->group);` when you test for the "search" permission.

Comment: `However you'll see the commented line in execute returns true but this doesn't seem to register with if(\Yii::$app->user->can('search'));` that must work. if you return true in your rule regardless of your user on your check for the search permission, and it not returns true then something else is wrong. is your rule executed at all? try a `die('test');`

Comment: By question 1 I meant that once the data is in the database or files, where in execute is it being read when in a group context? And if this is still required, where/how to you assign groups here, rather than users?

Comment: and @BHoft, if I do return true there, where does the RBAC tables come into play? I feel as though these tables are ignored, which is what I think I want. I'm still not making sense of this.

Comment: i have added some text to the post which was too long for the comment. I hope then it is more clear.